# ES6 - Yield and Return at the Same Time

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, yield, redux-saga

I have this,

```
function*(a){
 if (a) {
    yield API.callRoute();
    return;
  }
  // other stuff that is blocked by return
}
```

I want this:

```
function*(a){
  if (a) {
    return yield API.callRoute(); // one fewer line of code
  }
  //...
}
```

Doable? Why? Why not?

Comment: Well, have you tried your code? This actually should work...

Comment: I am a bit confused about your code. You do not seem to use the generator you create. is that correct?

Comment: @MoeSattler Yes this is a small piece of the app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable, but your second snippet `return`s the result of the `yield` expression. If you don't want that but make it exactly equivalent to your first snippet, use

```
return void yield API.callRoute();
```

though probably it's not worth making this a line shorter when the difference is significant.